# How to get the array values using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to get the array values using a foreach loop but getting `Undefined index` error. This is the var_dump result shown below.

```
       Array
    (
     [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 670
                [snippets_name] => flkgjfldgkjlfdkj ldkjfg lkgfjd lkjg 
                [snippets_keyword] => 
                [snippets_description] => dkjldkjflkfjldskfjldkfjlkjl
                [snippet_image] => https://i.imgur.com/4WAnAP7.jpg
                [snippet_tags] => 
                [snippet_tags_id] => 
                [seo_description] => Bootstrap example of 
             flkgjfldgkjlfdkj ldkjfg lkgfjd lkjg  using 
              Bootstrap,Javascript,jquery,CSS code Snippet By hitesh- 
               chauhan57765
                [snippets_html] => kfdlkjflkgjldkgjdlkgjdl l
                [snippets_css] => 
                [snippets_javascript] => 
                [bootstrap_version_id] => 5
                [javascript_version_id] => 1
                [font_version_id] => 2
                [url_slug] => flkgjfldgkjlfdkj-ldkjfg-lkgfjd-lkjg- 
                21588457
                [snippets_created_ip] => 127.0.0.1
                [snippets_category] => 0
                [is_verified] => 0
                [listed_by] => 28
                [date_modified] => 2019-09-22 04:57:31
                [date_created] => 2019-09-22 04:57:31
                [is_featured] => 0
                [search_values] => 
                [counter_views] => 2
                [avarage_rating] => 
                [main_image] => 
                [date_notify] => 
                [status] => 0
                [last_edit_ip] => 127.0.0.1
                [date_notify_expired] => 
            )

             )

        )
```

Here what I tried to get the results. But getting the Message: Undefined index: snippet_name error. please help.

```
                foreach($snippets_tags as $post)

                { 
               $listed_by = $post['snippets_name'];
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this code -

```
foreach ($snippets_tags as $snippets) {

                foreach($snippets as $key=>$post)

                { 
                    $listed_by = $post->listed_by;
                }
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
echo $snippets_tags[0][0]->snippets_name
```

Or , by using `foreach`

```
foreach($snippets_tags[0] as $post)
{ 
  echo $post->snippets_name;echo '<br/>';
}
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/D0aOi

Comment: But what if there is more the one item in the array?

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan  its depend on the depth of the array, may be you need to use 2 `foreach`

Comment: Can you please tell me How can i loop through with more then one item in the array

Comment: Check please let me know how can i loop through this - https://www.pastiebin.com/5d8719045f002

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan use 2 `foreach` Loop and echo inside the second `foreach`

Comment: Can't i use key value pair here?

Answer (score 1):

Dump shows that you have an arrays of objects (not arrays - that's why you're getting an "undefined index" message) nested in the outer array. So, to extract `snippets_name` property of each object, you will need two `foreach` cycles:

```php
$snippetsNames = [];
foreach ($data as $objects) {
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
       $snippetsNames[] = $object->{'snippets_name'} ?? 'Unknown name';
    }
}
```

Note that you can address object property by string, using curly braces syntax shown above. And you can also run into situation when there's no given property in the object; you should check that situation with `isset()` (or just use the short and convenient syntax with `??` shown above).

Comment: Curly braces and quotes are not needed. Curly braces are often used to wrap a variable. `$object->snippets_name`

Comment: In this case they are really not needed, but you will need them to access properties like `snippets-name` that violate PHP grammar for property names. Just wanted to show how it works to the author.